# Date formats/values change when file is opened programmatically

Tags: excel, vba, date, csv

I have .csv file which is a time series of daily data, with several data points associated with each date.

When I manually open the file, the dates open correctly, as the date format `dd/mm/yyyy`.

When I open the file programmatically, the dates up to the 12th of each month are opened as `mm/dd/yyyy`, although the format remains `dd/mm/yyyy` (e.g. the 1st of July 1983 (1/7/1983), would be opened as the 7th of January 1983 (7/1/1983) - this isn't just a formatting issue, the Julian Date (days since 1 Jan 1901) associated with these dates also changes), and the dates after the 12th of each month are opened correctly, although as text rather than a date.

The data coming in as text is not an issue, however, the dates changing as soon as the file is opened is problematic. I could try to import the entire .csv file as comma delimited text rather than opening the file, however, it would be easier and faster if I could stop the dates from changing when I open the file.

```
Flder = InputBox("Copy and Paste Folder path here:")

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set SourcePath = FSO.GetFolder(Flder)

For Each File In SourcePath.Files        
    Workbooks.Open (File)

    FlNm = File.Name

    StrtCol = Workbooks(FlNm).Worksheets(1).Range(Cells(4, 1), Cells(4, 30)).Find ("Mean").Column

    Workbooks(FlNm).Worksheets(1).Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(60000, 1)).Copy (Workbooks("Find Water Years V2.xls").Worksheets(1).Range("A3"))
    Workbooks(FlNm).Worksheets(1).Range(Cells(1, StrtCol), Cells(60000, StrtCol + 1)).Copy (Workbooks("Find Water Years V2.xls").Worksheets(1).Range("B3"))

    Workbooks(FlNm).Close
Next
```

The problem seems to occur at the line `Workbooks.Open(File)`.

Comment: Can you define "open programmatically"? Do you mean via Excel automation? Or directly in VBA code? There's no way "opening the file" could change any content; it's something other than that, but you've posted nothing pertinent to that in your question. Opening a .csv file does not do anything to change the content in itself (for instance, in Notepad); post some code or other info that shows how you're reading it and what you're doing with the text you read. Otherwise, I'd suspect your question is going to be closed as "not a real question". :)

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity on the one Ken, code below.

Comment: Have to agree with Ken here. There is an underlying cause. What does the file look like in notepad at that point, how are you opening the file? Is it being pulled into a template. Pasted?

Comment: The file is opened directly into excel using `Workbooks.Open(File)` (see the above code that I just pasted). When the data is opened in Notepad the dates are correct, in dd/mm/yyyy format, the same as when the file is opened manually.

Comment: What happens when you open a text-format file containing dates is going to depend on the format the dates are in and on your locale: if you're in the US it's going to try to make a date out of "7/1/1983" and it's going to read that as July 1, because in the US the month comes before the day.  Any case where the first value is >12 Excel won't parse into a date, so it stays as text.

Comment: I have tried your code and it fails in the way you say. For me, this is a new variation of the well-known bug that if a date can be treated as an American date it is. So given the chance, Excel will misinterpret "2/1/12" as the 1-Feb-12. What is unusual in this case is that "13/1/12" is treated as a string. Normally, "13/1/12" is correctly converted to 13-Jan-12. There have been several questions about this bug over the last few months.  I know of no fix except to use unambiguous date strings such as 13-Jan-12 which are imported correctly. BTW, Microsoft see this as a feature not a bug.

Comment: Sorry @Tim but you cannot avoid this bug by having you locale set for a country that uses little endian dates.  Functions such as DateValue are locale aware but other parts of Excel are not.  Clearly Workbook Open is a part that is not internationalised.

Comment: @Tony - did you check that?  I just set my locale to the UK and it correctly parsed the UK dates from "1/7/1993" to "25/7/1993" as being dates in July.  What locales did you compare?

Comment: So the root of the problem, and the discrepancy between manually opening the file (from Windows Explorer, or through 'File-> Open') and opening it through the code is that the manual opening methods recognise that I'm in Australia, and so would parse in the dates as dd/mm/yyyy, whereas `Workbooks.Open` fails to recognise my locale, and so uses the default mm/dd/yyyy? How awkward... Is there any way to force the data to be parsed in as text? This would serve my purposes, so long as the date remains correct...

Comment: @Tim, my current Locale is set to Australia, default date is dd/mm/yyyy. Did you parse in the data with code or manually?

Comment: @Tim, I'm assuming when you say you set Locale to the UK you went through Control Panel-> Regional and Language Options? Or is there somewhere that Locale can be set within Excel?

Comment: @Tony - my mistake you are correct! I guess I didn't restart XL between locales or something along those lines. I now see the difference between the two methods of opening the file...

Comment: Cheers for all the thoughts guys but I've found the workaround. Ridiculously simple once I realised it... I'll post the answer in a sec.

Comment: so, rep isn't high enough to answer my own just yet. The solution was to set the Local variant of `Workbooks.Open` to true, forcing it to parse in the data using the Local settings, rather than the default (US). If one of you want to answer the q feel free, otherwise I'll throw up the answer later this afternoon or tomorrow morning.

Comment: @Ben F. Glad you found the solution. I would not have thought of looking through the Open's parameters. Good thinking! Thanks for the offer but I do not think I am entitled to any points. I have upvoted your question; perhaps we can get you reputation up high enough for you to post the answer. Certainly I think you deserve some points for the question and even more for the answer.

Comment: Great solution, but the question that remains open: what if we have a macro that is going to be used in various locations **including** US? The solution will work outside of US but fail miserably in US.

Answer (score 13):

Since the question has already been answered by the OP in the comments but not posted as an official answer I'll put it here in case someone else misses it like I did.

```
workbook = workbooks.Open(filename, Local:= true)
```

By setting Local = true uses the local machines date format rather than assuming mdy so in locales such as Australia (dmy) it'll change the behavior of Open()

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this, as just had the same problem. While is obvious there is a local issue, is not as obvious what the fix is (unless you know each little function parameters out of your head). I can't see a reason why that option is not true by default.

Comment: Me either, given that when you open a file interactively it behaves as if Local:=True so I agree it should be the default

Answer (score 2):

I experienced this problem with **Office 365**.
With importing an **csv** file with Excel some dates *dd/mm/jjjj* (European) where imported as American dates *mm/dd/jjjj*. The **csv** file doesn't have any formatting of dates closed in.

By opening as follows:

```
Set xla = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set xlb = xla.Workbooks.Open(sFilePath, ReadOnly:=False, Local:=True)
```

The local settings where used, and problem solved :-)

Other options with opening a file are:

```
expression.Open (FileName, UpdateLinks, ReadOnly, 
                 Format, Password, WriteResPassword, 
                 IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended, Origin, 
                 Delimiter, Editable, Notify, Converter, 
                 AddToMru, Local, CorruptLoad)
```

Answer (score 0):

> > > I could try to import the entire .csv file as comma delimited text rather than actually opening the file, however, it would be easier and faster if I could stop the dates from changing when I open the file.

It is still fast if you open it as CDT. You simply use `.OpenText` instead of `.Open`. Rest of the code remains same :)

Try recording a macro and you will see that the code looks somewhat like this.

```
Workbooks.OpenText Filename:= File, _
Origin:=437, StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:= _
xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, Semicolon:=False, _
Comma:=True, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo:=Array(1, 1), _
TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
```

Comment: My experience is OpenText doesn't work if the dates aren't formatted mdy

Comment: No. But you can enforce importing **as a text**, manipulate the text to have correct unambiguous format (preferable ISO, which is YYYY-MM-DD) and apply CDate on such manipulated string.

Answer (score 0):

I found that user2981639 had the right idea, but I got a syntax error with 'Local: true' so
I used 'local:=True' instead

This problem was driving me nuts because I also had 2 memo fields in the csv file. 
If I tried to format the dates in any way the memo fields would not import correctly, they would either be truncated to 255 characters or any embedded CRLF characters would cut the record up into pieces depending on how many there were.

Thanks guys for posting

Answer (score 0):

Here, you see a working code with example. This problem frustrated me as well for a while. I was opening a .txt file in excel and the date I had use for was converting from dd-mm-yyyy format to mm-dd-yyyy format. Below you see  a solution. It lay in the last command (,Local := True). See below. Hope it helps.

```
Note that while trasferring .txt file to excel use File Origin as "xlWindows:
    Workbooks.OpenText Filename:= _
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Reporting").Cells(3, 6), Origin:=xlWindows, _
    StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlFixedWidth, FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 1), Array(49 _
    , 1), Array(50, 1), Array(67, 1), Array(80, 1), Array(93, 1), Array(106, 1), Array(119, 1)) _
    , DecimalSeparator:=",", ThousandsSeparator:=".", TrailingMinusNumbers:= _
    True, Local:=True
```

NOTE: rest above settings for array and decimal separator are my work specific - may not apply to you.

Answer (score 0):

I am also struggling to find an answer. However what resolves this problem is.:-

Local should be true.
and workbook close save changes must be false. That should work.

Answer (score 0):

Just had this problem myself and found the above solution

```
 workbook = workbooks.Open(filename, Local:= true)
```

to be problematic in that it generates an error message.  The MS documentation doesn't mention brackets or Workbook =, so I used this:-

```
 Workbooks.Open Path, local:=True
```

Worked form me, hope it helps you.