# Complications changing excel string to date value in VBA - American vs English Dates

Tags: excel, vba, date, format

I'm currently trying to code a macro to open a set of reports in a folder and create some summary reporting over all the reports. Part of this involves doing a WorksheetFunction.SumIfs using a set of dates. The dates in column M of the .csv report I am using are stored as text, so I believe I need to convert them first. However, when I try and convert the dates as per the below:

```
Dim MyBook As ActiveWorkbook
Dim Cel As Range
For Each Cel In MyBook.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Columns("M").Cells
     If Cel.Row <> 1 Then 'this ensures it does not try and convert the header
          Cel.Value = DateValue(Cel.Value)
     End If
Next
```

It actually converts one of the dates (12/11/2018, i.e. 12th November) into it's U.S. format (11/12/2018, i.e. 11th December). This only happens in a few instances. Is there a way that anyone knows of that I can use to stop this happening? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Open the CSV with [OpenText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbooks.opentext) and provide `xlDMYFormat` for the relevant columns in the `FieldInfo` argument.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `Cel.Value = DateValue(Cel.Value)`

try

```
Cel.Value = CDate(Cel.Value)
```

Comment: Both `DateValue` and `CDate` respect the system date format.

Answer (score 0):

CDate didn't work because the date had already been Americanised - however by opening the csv file using Local=:True I was able to get the date in the correct format. [Excel VBA date formats/values change when file is opened programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9626294/excel-vba-date-formats-values-change-when-file-is-opened-programatically)

Thanks for your help