# Copying dates from CSV into Excel while retaining date formatting

Tags: excel, vba, date, number-formatting

I copy information from various CSV files into an Excel sheet. The files are reports from Symantec that include last scan dates, definitions dates etc.

When I look at the CSV in Excel, the dates are formatted as Custom dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm.

I'm trying, with a VBA script, to run through these files and list the information for systems that haven't scanned in 30 days.

When the information is copied some of the date formats become General, and show the correct format dd/mm/yyyy.
Others become Custom, and switch the values of the dates to mm/dd/yyyy but keep the display the same. So instead of reading 01/12/2020 as 1st of December, it reads it as 12th January. Any date that stars with a number 1-12 seems to be read as mm/dd/yyyy and not the dd/mm/yyyy format that the original is configured as.

Is there VBA code to convert date values on the CSV to Long number before copying them into the Excel sheet and them converting that number back to a date format?

I tried using the .numberformat "dd/mm/yyyy" options and .numberformat "General".

To open each CSV file I do the following:

```
strFile = Dir(strSourcePath & "*.csv")
Cnt = Cnt + 1
    If Cnt = 1 Then
        r=2
    Else
        r = Cells(rows.count, "A").End(xlUp) + 1
    End If

Open strSourcepath & strFile For Input as #1
    inputRow = 1
        Line Input #1, strData
        If inputRow > 1 Then
            inputRow - inputRow +1
                X = Split(strData, ",")
                For c = 0 To UBound(X)
                    Cells(r, c + 1).Value = Trim(X(c))
                Next c
                r = r + 1
            Else
                inputRow = inputRow + 1
            End If
        Loop
    Close #1
    strFile = Dir
    Loop
```

Comment: While stepping through the code, I've also found that it's basically copying each comma separated value using the trim command into the targeted cell. I found that in VBA, the String value is 01/12/2020 but as soon as it's copied into the sheet it is changed to 12/01/2020. I'd love to know what's causing this

Comment: Could you include a couple of lines from your CSV file?

Comment: That could take a while, as I have no direct access between my Internet PC and the one I'm working on. I may have some sample data I can include later from my test workstation in my other office. The file has over 90 columns and over 1000 lines, I'm trying to import multiple CSVs from a single folder, hence I can't really just import the csv manually.

Comment: I can't copy even a single line as it takes me over the character limit. I can show the cells that I'm having trouble with:
12/07/2020
11/08/2020 12:41
19/09/2020 07:26:55

The top two dates would reverse to 7th Dec and 8th Nov while the bottom would remain 19th Sep. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I store dates as Long data type.

Imagine in cell A1 there's :

```
1/12/20
```

This is [december 1st, 2020], not 12th January.
So my code would be:

```
dim MyDate as long
MyDate = Clng(CDate(Cells(1,1)))
```

So, now I can work with the Date as a long data type and do whatever in VBA. And when I need to print out, Excel for sure will know which date is.

Comment: I think the problem is the way it's reading the CSV file. It's essentially reading the entire line of CSV data, then using the trim command to take the information from the appropriate section of that line, so it's not reading it as anything other than a string, then when the information is being added into the cell, excel is interpreting it as a date and converting it to the wrong format. When the date is obviously UK format, it doesn't do that. 

Is there a better way to read the multiple CSV files into a single worksheet within my project?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So, the issue has been resolved with a slightly more in-depth way of doing it.

I now use the workbook.open(filename, local:=True) option to open the CSV, this keeps the date formatting correct.

Then I simply use the TargetCell("range").value = SourceCell("Range").value command to copy the data across.

Thanks for trying guys. I stumbled across the same issue at [Date formats/values change when file is opened programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9626294/date-formats-values-change-when-file-is-opened-programmatically)

This got my file open correctly, then I could adjust my code accordingly.